# What should I do to setup a new Gremlin version for Neo4j?

Tags: configuration, neo4j, dbpedia, gremlin

I am using `Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel 1.8`

It uses this gremlin version:

```
gremlin> Gremlin.version()
==> 1.5
```

which is very old version.

I want to upgrade to `gremlin` `2.0` or `2.1` from [the github project](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/downloads), since I can't run this command on `gremlin 1.5`:

```
gremlin> g.v(1).outE.has("weight", T.gte, 0.5f).weight
==> No such property: T for class: groovysh_evaluate
```

My question is what should I do, so I won't mess up all the entire environment of `neo4j`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run:

```
import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.Tokens.T
```

To call the gremlin helper Tokens ("T") directly:

```
g.v(1).outE.has("weight", T.gte, 0.5f).weight
```

Or you can write:

```
g.v(0).outE.has("weight", Tokens.T.gte, 0.5f).weight
```

Write it in the gremlin shell.

Answer (score 1):

the Gremlin plugin and the server will be upgraded in the next weeks, is that ok?